# Symmetric Expressions in Roots of Polynomial with Coefficients in Integral Domain

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-integers

Recently I learned about Pisot-Vijayaraghavan numbers, and proofs around them led me to the fact that the sums of $n$th powers of roots of a monic irreducible integer polynomial are integers. I saw a proof, but it used power series, and I thought it must be provable with Galois Theory, so I came up with this shorter proof:

Let $p=\sum_{i=0}^np_ix^i$, $p_n\neq0$ be a monic irreducible integer polynomial with roots $\alpha_1$ to $\alpha_n$, and let $f\in\mathbb{Z}[\alpha_1,...\alpha_n]$ be a symmetric expression in the roots. Then $f$ evaluates to an integers.

By Guass's Lemma we know that $p$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$ and thus separable. So its splitting field $\mathbb{Q}_f$ is Galois. $f$ is fixed by all automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}_f$ since they all must fix the set of roots of $p$. Hence, $f\in\mathbb{Q}$. But since algebraic integers form a ring $f$ is an algebraic integer, say a root of integer polynomial $q$. Now $q$ factors in $\mathbb{Q}$ and by Gauss's Lemma, in $\mathbb{Z}$. One of these factors must have root $f$, so we  apply again, until we obtain that $x-f$ is an integer polynomial, so $f\in\mathbb{Z}$.

I was wondering how far this could be generalised. I know it works if we replace $\mathbb{Z}$ with an integral domain of characteristic $0$, and $\mathbb{Q}$ with its field of fractions. However, I was wondering if we could drop the characteristic $0$ condition. My proof does not generalise since it relies on irreducible polynomials being separable.

Comment: The polynomial does not have to be irreducible.  You only need to have the Vieta relations hold. Then it works in general in arbitrary commutative rings.

Comment: Do I need the polynomial $p$ to be monic? I don't see where I've used it.

Comment: Any symmetric expression in the roots is a polynomial in the basic symmetric functions, which are $-p_{n-1}/p_n$, $p_{n-2}/p_n$, $\ldots$, $(-1)^n p_0/p_n$.  If $p_n$ is not $1$, you might end up with rational, but not integers.  For instance, you can have the polynomial $3 + 2 x$.

Comment: Oh right it's in the factorisation step. Thanks.